# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file python

Tags: python

i'm relatively new to programing and i wanted to create a bit of Python code that simply searches for , and replaces them with a dot, on certain number and character sequences. it needs to run on large files. so i came up with this.

```
import re


f = open('filein.txt','r')
o = open ('fileout4.txt','w')

newdata=f.read()
rc=re.compile('(?<=..\d)[,]')
for line in newdata:
        newdataline=newdata
        newline = rc.sub('.',newdata)
        o.write(newline)
        f.close()
        o.close()
f.close()
o.close()
```

it appears to work , but i still get this error message.

```
  File "C:\Python34\replace comma to dot usingresubtestnewlinecharacter.py", line 12, in ?
    o.write(newline)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

can anyone help here?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `close` statements from the for loop

```
for line in newdata:
        newdataline=newdata
        newline = rc.sub('.',newdata)
        o.write(newline)    # This is fine, remove the next two close statements!
```

The files are closed in the first iteration itself! That's why the next time the loop iterates, you will get the error.

**Or**  - *As you prefer to do*

```
for line in newdata:
        newdataline=newdata
        newline = rc.sub('.',newdata)
        o = open ('fileout4.txt','w') # Open the file inside the loop (I prefer 'a' instead of 'w')
        o.write(newline)            
        o.close()                     # Get rid of f.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, if i do this, the shell takes forever to execute on a 20mb file. if  i close the file as i did before it appears to work

Comment: I'm afraid that the program still hangs if i implement it the way you suggested. your code works on smaller files, ie. 100 kb and although my first suggestion provides an error message on larger files, 20mb, it still provides me with the output. is there another way one can write this code in an efficient way?

Comment: @Tom365 Bro, this is the most efficient way to solve. However of you want it to be more efficient, I suggest that you ask another question! I answered this question and helped you remove the `ValueError` which you got. I understand your situation as even I have worked on Big data and python regex is very slow!.